# What are the key areas to evaluate software (codebase) on?

Tags: architecture, programming-practices, object-oriented-design, code-quality, coding-standards

I have been asked to do a **code review** of about 50 applications over a period of 6 weeks. (Management has changed and the new CTO asked for an full internal software audit)

I am wondering, **what are the key areas to evaluate software on?** 
(The focus should purely be on the quality of the codebase and not e.g. how it was deployed)

**Please note:** This is **not** the same question as "What are the 9 or 10 qualities of software?".

The first few things that came to my mind are:

1. Code readability (descriptive variable/method/class names, comments etc)
2. Layering (data/business/UI)
3. Configuration (no hardcoding)
4. Sufficient level of abstraction (to remain flexible)
5. Organisation of the code
6. Use of 3rd party libraries (approved or not etc)
7. Separation of concerns
8. Test coverage (if applicable)
9. Modularity of code
10. Penalties for breaking principles such as "DRY"
11. ...

I will appreciate your answers to help me identify an extensive list of what you think are the key areas for software evaluation.

Comment: Have you been told WHY you have been asked? There may be specific objectives: security audit, potential acquisition, etc.

Comment: And the obligatory link to the [only real metric for code](http://blog.codinghorror.com/whos-your-coding-buddy/) - WTFs per minute.

Comment: @paj28 good point, I'll put it in the question - reason = audit

Comment: My guess is none of the above. Stop thinking like a Programmer and think more like a CTO.  He is interested in things like Cost/benefit, Security, Can I hire prorammers/contractor with the skills to maintain it, do I have key person vulnerability. Is the code Maintainable, how hard/expensive is to change (compared to a "new" system), will it run on new hardware and updated OS's... 

If he is thinking at the level you have described, he is a programmer, not a CTO.

Comment: Good point @manttnz.

Comment: An alternative could be to entirely sidestep the massive task of reviewing 50 apps in 6 weeks, and instead focus on the processes which produced those 50 apps. Do the teams use version control, continuous integration, TDD, pair programming, code reviews, cross-functional teams with good communication and tight feedback loops? If they do use CI, do they actually react to test failures from their CI builds or just ignore them? Do they document their design decisions? Do they pay down their technical debt? If the processes are sound, you can be reasonably sure that the apps will be as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

50 applications in 6 weeks sounds enormously ambitious. You need to tell your new CTO that this is only a lightweight review; there's no way you're going to detect bugs or security flaws in this time.

I'm mostly familiar with code review for security, and the rule of thumb I use is 10 KLOC per day - and even that is ambitious, and can only be achieved by focusing on the parts of code that really matter for security.

A few suggestions:

- Design a report template at the beginning, and get the CTO to approve this. It should be concise: a few red/amber/green statuses for different areas, maybe a few list of key people, issues, etc.
- Include documentation in your review. This could include tickets on your issue tracker.
- Speak to key people related to each application. This lets you get to the important issues more quickly.
- Establish what coding standards you have, and whether they are mandatory or advisory.
- Take a risk-based approach, where you spend more time on applications that matter more.
- Try to establish whether you could reasonably make changes to the application. You sound like you've got decent coding skills: if you think you'd struggle, this is clearly a concern for future maintenance of the app.

Apart from that, good luck! This is an opportunity to shine, so make the most of it.